# Application Insights Analysis Query

Tags: sql, azure, azure-application-insights, ms-app-analytics

What is the equivalent for:

```
SELECT operation_Id, Min(timestamp)
FROM exceptions
WHERE timestamp >= '2017-01-01'
GROUP BY operation_Id
```

on the Azure Application Insights analytics platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [summarize operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-reference#summarize-operator) like this:

```
exceptions
| where timestamp >= datetime('2017-01-01')
| summarize min(timestamp) by operation_Id
```